# How to use using with delete from in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-delete

Trying to do a inner join kinda in a delete statement in oracle. Here is the code.

```
delete podium_core.pd_field_tag t1
 using podium_core.pd_field_tag t2
 where t1.nid < t2.nid
   and t1.tag = t2.tag
   and t1.field_nid = t2.field_nid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query has nothing to do with Oracle.  It is Postgres syntax.  Instead, use a correlated subquery:

```
    delete from podium_core.pd_field_tag t1
    where t1.nid < (select t2.nid
                    from podium_core.pd_field_tag t2
                    where t1.tag = t2.tag and
                          t1.field_nid = t2.field_nid
                   );
```

Answer (score 0):

`Using` in `delete` statement is not allowed in oracle.

Try this:

```
delete from podium_core.pd_field_tag t1
Where (t1.nid, t1.tag, t1.field_nid) in
(Select t2.nid, t2.tag, t2.field_nid
   From podium_core.pd_field_tag t2
  WHERE t1.nid < t2.nid
    AND t1.tag = t2.tag
    AND t1.field_nid = t2.field_nid);
```

Cheers!!